# Creating a filter in the view using AngularFire/Firebase query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am building an app in which the user inputs tastings, and those tastings are displayed in a few places - on the user's personal tastings page, and on a "latest tastings" style page.

On the tastings page, when a button is clicked, a "basicTastings()" function is called, and that's where I want to query the DB and for the view to update with only those tastings which have the "Type: Basic" (thee is also type: advanced).

In that function, my test console log is properly outputting that a key() is basic/advanced.  Where I'm lost is in then pushing that object into the scope so that only those objects now go through the ng-repeat.

Finally - does it even make sense for me to be doing it this way?  I was approaching it in this manner instead of through, say, a jQuery .click() filtering idea because I thought it was a better approach if I end up with large amounts of data in the DB.

My data is set up as:

```
{
  "tastings" : {
    "-JlUCGqbLssTeob7weQI" : {
      "brewdate" : "2015-03-28T07:07:04.880Z",
      "origin" : "Panama",
      "overallrating" : 4.5,
      "roaster" : "Verve",
      "roastname" : "Los Lajones Honey",
      "subdate" : 1427526458869,
      "thoughts" : "Cup Characteristics: This Honey-Process coffee from Los Lajones is abdundantly juicy and filled with lovely stone fruit notes like Bing cherry and apricot. The body is like a perfectly tempered ganache.",
      "type" : "basic",
      "user" : "simplelogin:19"
    }
  },
    "simplelogin:19" : {
      "date" : 1427086513603,
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "regUser" : "simplelogin:19",
      "username" : "Tester"
    }
  }
}
```

My controller for listing the tastings is:

```
myApp.controller('TastingsListController',
  function($scope, $firebaseArray, $rootScope, $location, Authentication, FIREBASE_URL) {

    $scope.$emit('callForAuth'); // Emitter to initiate $onAuth function in Authentication service 

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/tastings');

    var tastingsInfo = $firebaseArray(ref);

    $scope.filterBasic = function() {

        ref.orderByChild("type").on("child_added", function(tasting) {
            console.log(tasting.key() + ' is a ' + tasting.val().type + ' tasting.');
            if(tasting.val().type === "basic") {
                tastingsInfo.push(tasting);
                console.log(tastingsInfo);
            }
    });
    };
  });
```

And finally the relevant ng-repeat and the button to trigger the function:

```
                <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" ng-click="filterBasic()" flex>
                    Basic
                </md-button>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <div class="basiccontainer" ng-repeat="tasting in tastings | orderBy: 'brewdate'">
```

**EDIT:** The data I'm getting in my console.log occurs after each tasting that is "basic", which is where it should be happening, but it contains the entire array of objects, when I want it to contain the object only, and then I want to put that object into an array that I can then iterate on with ng-repeat.

**Edit 2:** I think I'm approaching this whole thing wrong:

I've been reading and re-reading, and I think I see now where my approach is, basically, exactly what the Firebase docs are saying not to do:

- **Regarding my data structure and filtering by user for their own tastings:** Currently, I'm not indexing anything meaning that, as the data changes, I have to iterate through everything to see who owns what.
- What I SHOULD be doing in my case is to, when a user submits a Tasting, to have a user index within the tasting, even if it's just going to ever have one creator, also also have the tasting's key indexed with the user, e.g.:

Tasting:

```
"tastings" : {
    "-JlUCGqbLssTeob7weQI" : {
      "brewdate" : "2015-03-28T07:07:04.880Z",
      "origin" : "Panama",
      "overallrating" : 4.5,
      "roaster" : "Verve",
      "roastname" : "Los Lajones Honey",
      "subdate" : 1427526458869,
      "thoughts" : "Cup Characteristics: This Honey-Process coffee from Los Lajones is abdundantly juicy and filled with lovely stone fruit notes like Bing cherry and apricot. The body is like a perfectly tempered ganache.",
      "type" : "basic",
        "user" : {
           "simplelogin:18": true,
        },
    },
```

User:

```
    "users" : {
        "simplelogin:18" : {
          "date" : 1427062799596,
          "email" : "test@test.com",
          "regUser" : "simplelogin:18",
          "username" : "Tester",
            "tastings" : {
               "-JlUCGqbLssTeob7weQI": true,
               "<Tasting 2 Key>": true,
               ...
             },          
        },
```

This setup will allow me to actually set up a two-way relationship between a tasting and its creator.  I can do this all through the same submit function for when the user presses the "Submit" button - send the data for the tasting, as well use that tasting's key over to the user's tastings index.

- **Regarding my user of the controller vs a service:** What I'm doing right now is trying to do everything in the controller.
- What I SHOULD be doing is to, from the controller, call a "listingsfilter" service (or whatever I decide to call it) when the function within my controller is called via the button press.  That service itself should be doing the actual work of querying the Firebase for the listings, putting them into an array of some kind, and sending that back out to the controller, who then just feeds that data to the $scope through which the ng-repeat will iterate.

Comment: You can use the Firebase query [`equalTo()` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html) to accomplish this. Your query would look like `ref.orderByChild("type").equalTo("basic");`

Comment: Thanks, @jacobawenger.

The more I think about it, and read through the docs, I feel that I may be approaching this all wrong.  I'm adding an edit to explain my findings.